# ANGULAR Firebase FCM send are success but not visible

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've setup my angular 5 (jhipster) web app to receive FCM message. When i send a FCM message, i got a success in POST man but nothing appear in my browser or receiveMessage() function.

Here is my setup :

**My Project :**

**MessagingService**

```
@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {

  messaging = firebase.messaging()

  constructor() { }

  updateToken(token) {
    console.log("to update : {}", token)
  }

  getPermission() {
      this.messaging.requestPermission()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.');
        return this.messaging.getToken()
      })
      .then(token => {
        console.log(token)
        this.updateToken(token)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
      });
    }

    receiveMessage() {
       this.messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
        console.log("Message received. ", payload);
      });

    }
}
```

MessageService is initialised in main.component.ts :

**main.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-main',
    templateUrl: './main.component.html'
})
export class JhiMainComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private msgService: MessagingService
    ) {
        this.msgService.getPermission()
        this.msgService.receiveMessage()
    }

}
```

And here is my app.module.ts

**app.module.ts**

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { environment } from './environment';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        ...
     ],
     ...
     bootstrap: [JhiMainComponent]
})
```

I have also a webworker :

**firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: <apiKey>,
    authDomain: <authDomain>,
    databaseURL: <databaseURL>,
    projectId: <projectId>,
    storageBucket: <storageBucket>,
    messagingSenderId: <messagingSenderId>
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

And to conclude, my manifest.webapp and .angular-cli.json

**manifest.webapp**

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "short_name": "project",
  "gcm_sender_id": "103953800507",
   ...
}
```

**.angular-cli.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "project": {
        "name": "project"
    },
    "apps": [{
        "root": "src/main/webapp",
        "outDir": "build/www/app",
        "assets": [
            "content",
            "favicon.ico",
            "firebase-messaging-sw.js",
            "manifest.webapp"
            ]
            ....
```

**How i send a notif :**

**Postman** :

```
{
    "to" : "enxeahE8....ETux", // token from console.log of MessageService.getPermission() 
    "data" : {
        "body" : "First Notification",
        "title": "ALT App Testing"
    }
}
```

Then i got a success like that :

```
{
    "multicast_id": <multicast_id>,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": <message_id>
        }
    ]
}
```

But nothing enter in receiveMessage() of MessageService or appear on the screen.

Help please :(

Comment: Works in https and not http, that s why it didn't work => https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546288/5193930

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you aren't on active tab. Only when you are on active tab, receiveMessage() function will be called. Otherwise background message will be called.
Hope it will be helpful