# Unable to send push notification - failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send out a push notification from a web based client to similar clients. I have managed to implement on the receiving end, however I am unable to send due to the following error:

**Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: Failed to fetch. Error code: undefined".**

My firebase initialization file:

```
import firebase from "firebase";

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBhQV8zHeo7piFalXcA14v6hV*****",
  authDomain: "*****-demo-a82ca.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://*****-demo-a82ca.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "*****demo-a82ca",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "52526034576",
  appId: "1:52526034576:web:7b271318a*****"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebaseApp.firestore();
export const firebaseMessaging = firebaseApp.messaging()
firebaseMessaging.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

And the js file doing the sending:

```
import { firebaseMessaging } from "@/firebase/init";

sendNotification() {
  this.broadcastingAnnouncement = true;
  console.log("Selected audience: ", this.selectedAudience);

  var registrationToken =
    "ezdWAWsKo48:APA91bF************"; //Client to receive the notification

  var message = {
    data: {
      title: "Hello World",
      body: "Test message"
    },
    token: registrationToken
  };

firebaseMessaging
    .messaging()
    .send(message)
    .then(response => {
      // Response is a message ID string.
      console.log("Successfully sent notification:", response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });
}
```

What could be my issue here? (I have confirmed that my api key is correct)

Comment: Can you check your local machine time? could be OS clock is not syncronised

Comment: can you check outbound connection from your server. error code: undefined can be erro rin connecting to the external service.

Comment: Check this post to see if it helps
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462400/not-receiving-fcm-push-notification-for-web-on-localhost/49209072#49209072)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it seems you are trying to use [client side SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js) to send push messages, although you should use [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message).

The code above anyway looks curiously:

1. Why do you call `initializeApp()` on you `firebaseMessaging` object, which [doesn't have such method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging.html)
2. Why do you call `firebaseMessaging.messaging()`, `firebaseMessaging` object is already a `Messaging` instance